# Getting null values when binding values from an HttpRequest to an Object in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, twilio, lombok, hikaricp

I've created a Webhook server that's accepting a POST request from a 3rd party (Twilio) for their message delivery call-backs and I'm de-serializing it into an object.
The pojo object has the same attribute names as coming in the POST requests.

When I print the pojo object, I'm getting null for 2 fields and the rest are correctly assigned.

When I print the entire POST request itself I see that the 2 fields are coming in correctly and I'm not sure what am I doing wrong?

For the pojo class I'm using Lombok for the getter and setters.

The 2 fields that are coming in the request which are resulting in a null are Phone numbers and I'm declaring them as Strings because they are coming in as JSON.

Here is what the code looks like :

```
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
public class StatusDeliveryModel {

    @JsonProperty("SmsSid")
    private String SmsSid;
    @JsonProperty("SmsStatus")
    private String SmsStatus;
    @JsonProperty("MessageStatus")
    private String MessageStatus;
    @JsonProperty("To")
    private String ToNumber;
    @JsonProperty("MessageSid")
    private String MessageSid;
    @JsonProperty("From")
    private String FromNumber;
    @JsonProperty("ApiVersion")
    private String ApiVersion;

}
```

```
@RestController
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    private MyDataService myDataService;

    @PostMapping("/insert")
    public void insertIntoDatabase(@ModelAttribute StatusDeliveryModel statusDeliveryModel, HttpServletRequest request){

        System.out.println(statusDeliveryModel.toString());

        Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
            String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);
            System.out.println(paramName + "': " + paramValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the response :

```
StatusDeliveryModel(SmsSid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, SmsStatus=queued, MessageStatus=queued, ToNumber=null, MessageSid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, FromNumber=null, ApiVersion=2010-04-01)

SmsSid': XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
SmsStatus': queued
MessageStatus': queued
To': +1518XXXXXXX
MessageSid': XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
From': +1213XXXXXXX
ApiVersion': 2010-04-01
```

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

dependencies in the project are :

1. spring-boot-starter-jdbc
2. mysql-connector-j
3. spring-boot-starter-web
4. spring-boot-starter-test
5. HikariCP
6. lombok
7. spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Last scenario is I can parse the values from the HttpServletRequest and set the values using the setter methods but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I need to see the request body in order to say whether you’ve a problem with the binding, but in general, `@ModelAttribute` is a Spring MVC concept, and since you don’t have a view to return, you can just use `@RequestBody` instead.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/sms-webhooks

According to this article the request body will look something like this


SmsSid: SM2xxxxxx
SmsStatus: sent
MessageStatus: sent
To: +1512zzzyyyy
MessageSid: SM2xxxxxx
AccountSid: ACxxxxxxx
From: +1512xxxyyyy
ApiVersion: 2010-04-01